# I can not realize the task of transferring from xlsx to csv

Tags: python, csv, openpyxl, xlsx

Condition:

*In the Excel office program (or its analogues), you can always save the table in csv format.*

*Imagine that this functionality is broken.*
*Write your own excel -> csv transcoder using the appropriate libraries.*
*Your program should open the data.xlsx file containing arbitrary data and save the result in output.csv*

*Input format
Not*

*Output format
In the output.csv file, output data from the source file in csv format.
Separator - "semicolon"
Quotation - quotation marks*

*Notes
Use the csv module*

***My code:***

```
import csv
import openpyxl
from openpyxl import Workbook

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(filename='data.xlsx', data_only=True)
with open('output.csv', 'w', newline='', encoding="utf8") as csvfile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=';', quotechar='"')
    for ws in wb:
        for row in ws.iter_rows():
            line = []
            for v in row:
                line.append(str(v.value))
            writer.writerow(line)
```

***for some reason real numbers do not pass***

[image]

Comment: At least for me real numbers do actually pass. openpyxl just seems to convert numbers with a decimal fraction of 0 into integers, which seems to happen in your case as well. Just have a look at the last element of each row.

Comment: Using `str()` is going let Python decide. Use string formatting if you want more control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it okay if I could suggest you to use pandas?

```
import pandas as pd


full_dataset = pd.read_xls('file.xlsx')
```

Assuming that it has 2 worksheets

```
full_dataset['worksheet1'].to_csv('worksheet1.csv', index = False, headers = True)
full_dataset['worksheet2'].to_csv('worksheet2.csv', index = False, headers = True)
```

And you are done. Have a nice day!

Comment: Not really suitable for very large files because it adds an intermediate step. It's easy enough with openpyxl.

Comment: But Excels have a limitation to be functional and usable, and as long as it's not a relational database with more than 1 million records. This is more than sufficient.

Comment: Dataframes are in memory objects and are not required here. The deficiencis of the XLSX file format are well known but not relevant here.